# How to compare type of an object in Python?

Tags: python, types, compare

Basically I want to do this:

```
obj = 'str'
type ( obj ) == string
```

I tried:

```
type ( obj ) == type ( string )
```

and it didn't work.

Also, what about the other types? For example, I couldn't replicate `NoneType`.

Comment: This works `type(obj) == str`

Comment: str is a class whereas string can be a variable but it has to be defined first. So, unless you have defined what the word "string" is, it is just text.
For e.g.: 
string = 5
print(type(string)) //this will give the class/dtype of the variable, which, in this case was int

Answer (score 330, accepted):

```
isinstance()
```

In your case, `isinstance("this is a string", str)` will return `True`.

You may also want to read this: http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/

Comment: I'd say you (the OP) should *definitely* read the referenced link, which gives plenty of details of why checking the type of an object is usually a bad idea, and what you probably should be doing instead.

Comment: you should use basestr, not str. otherwise you will not pick unicode. (although for 3.x I think str *is* the basestr)

Answer (score 53):

First, avoid all type comparisons.  They're very, very rarely necessary.  Sometimes, they help to check parameter types in a function -- even that's rare.  Wrong type data will raise an exception, and that's all you'll ever need.

All of the basic conversion functions will map as equal to the type function.

```
type(9) is int
type(2.5) is float
type('x') is str
type(u'x') is unicode
type(2+3j) is complex
```

There are a few other cases.

```
isinstance( 'x', basestring )
isinstance( u'u', basestring )
isinstance( 9, int )
isinstance( 2.5, float )
isinstance( (2+3j), complex )
```

None, BTW, never needs any of this kind of type checking.  None is the only instance of NoneType.  The None object is a Singleton.  Just check for None

```
variable is None
```

BTW, do not use the above in general.  Use ordinary exceptions and Python's own natural polymorphism.

Comment: If you're validating inputs from a DSL, you need all this, even `NoneType`. What if a parameter can be a `str`, `unicode`, or `None`? `isinstance(x, (str, unicode, types.NoneType))` is much cleaner than checking for `None`. If you're building tools for deferred computation, or if you're about to launch a long or resource-intensive process, it is valuable to catch `type` errors ahead of time, during some custom validation step. This has been a critical part of almost every scientific computing project I've ever worked on. Out of all dev projects I've seen, more have needed this than have not.

Comment: What about comparing `type` directly, instead? For example `test(t1: Type, t2: Type) -> bool `? What are the best practices and the docs guidelines there?

Answer (score 44):

`isinstance` works:

```
if isinstance(obj, MyClass): do_foo(obj)
```

**but**, keep in mind: if it looks like a duck, and if it sounds like a duck, it is a duck.

EDIT:  For the None type, you can simply do:

```
if obj is None: obj = MyClass()
```

Comment: `def distance_from_zero(n):
    if isinstance(n,int) or isinstance(n,float):
        return abs(n)
    else:
        return "Nope"
        
print distance_from_zero(True)`

This returns a "1" instead of "Nope". How to get around this ?

Comment: If you want to use `isinstance` but check also for `None` then `isinstance(obj, (MyClass, type(None)))` works. `types.NoneType` has been removed from Python 3 so it is not as portable as `type(None)` to get a reference to `NoneType`.

Answer (score 26):

For other types, check out the [types](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) module:

```
>>> import types
>>> x = "mystring"
>>> isinstance(x, types.StringType)
True
>>> x = 5
>>> isinstance(x, types.IntType)
True
>>> x = None
>>> isinstance(x, types.NoneType)
True
```

P.S. Typechecking is a bad idea.

Answer (score 20):

You can always use the `type(x) == type(y)` trick, where `y` is something with known type.

```
# check if x is a regular string
type(x) == type('')
# check if x is an integer
type(x) == type(1)
# check if x is a NoneType
type(x) == type(None)
```

Often there are better ways of doing that, particularly with any recent python.  But if you only want to remember one thing, you can remember that.

In this case, the better ways would be:

```
# check if x is a regular string
type(x) == str
# check if x is either a regular string or a unicode string
type(x) in [str, unicode]
# alternatively:
isinstance(x, basestring)
# check if x is an integer
type(x) == int
# check if x is a NoneType
x is None
```

Note the last case: there is only one instance of `NoneType` in python, and that is `None`.  You'll see NoneType a lot in exceptions (`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable` -- happens to me all the time..) but you'll hardly ever need to refer to it in code.

Finally, as fengshaun points out, type checking in python is not always a good idea.  It's more pythonic to just use the value as though it is the type you expect, and catch (or allow to propagate) exceptions that result from it.

Comment: For what it's worth, isinstance() is the preferred way of checking types in Python (when you have to do it).

Answer (score 12):

Use `isinstance(object, type)`. As above this is easy to use if you know the correct `type`, e.g.,

```
isinstance('dog', str) ## gives bool True
```

But for more esoteric objects, this can be difficult to use. 
For example:

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([1,2,3]) 
isinstance(a,np.array) ## breaks
```

but you can do this trick:

```
y = type(np.array([1]))
isinstance(a,y) ## gives bool True
```

So I recommend instantiating a variable (`y` in this case) with a type of the object you want to check (e.g., `type(np.array())`), then using `isinstance`.

Answer (score 10):

You're very close! `string` is a module, not a type. You probably want to compare the type of `obj` against the type object for strings, namely `str`:

```
type(obj) == str  # this works because str is already a type
```

Alternatively:

```
type(obj) == type('')
```

Note, in Python 2, if `obj` is a unicode type, then neither of the above will work. Nor will `isinstance()`. See John's comments to this post for how to get around this... I've been trying to remember it for about 10 minutes now, but was having a memory block!

Comment: Use basestring with isinstance() to get both str and unicode.

Answer (score 8):

Use str instead of string

```
type ( obj ) == str
```

Explanation

```
>>> a = "Hello"
>>> type(a)==str
True
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is because you have to write

```
s="hello"
type(s) == type("")
```

type accepts an instance and returns its type. In this case you have to compare two instances' types.

If you need to do preemptive checking, it is better if you check for a supported interface than the type.

The type does not really tell you much, apart of the fact that your code want an instance of a specific type, regardless of the fact that you could have another instance of a completely different type which would be perfectly fine because it implements the same interface.

For example, suppose you have this code

```
def firstElement(parameter):
    return parameter[0]
```

Now, suppose you say: I want this code to accept only a tuple.

```
import types

def firstElement(parameter):
    if type(parameter) != types.TupleType:
         raise TypeError("function accepts only a tuple")
    return parameter[0]
```

This is reducing the reusability of this routine. It won't work if you pass a list, or a string, or a numpy.array. Something better would be

```
def firstElement(parameter):
    if not (hasattr(parameter, "__getitem__") and callable(getattr(parameter,"__getitem__"))):
        raise TypeError("interface violation")
    return parameter[0]
```

but there's no point in doing it: parameter[0] will raise an exception if the protocol is not satisfied anyway... this of course unless you want to prevent side effects or having to recover from calls that you could invoke before failing. (Stupid) example, just to make the point:

```
def firstElement(parameter):
    if not (hasattr(parameter, "__getitem__") and callable(getattr(parameter,"__getitem__"))):
        raise TypeError("interface violation")
    os.system("rm file")
    return parameter[0]
```

in this case, your code will raise an exception before running the system() call. Without interface checks, you would have removed the file, and then raised the exception.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the actual preferred way to check for interfaces. Many of the answers here mention it, but few give examples of what's good instead. It still doesn't answer my personal question directly (I'm trying to separate a list of strings, containing many, meaningful items, from a string, which contains many, not meaningful items. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I use `type(x) == type(y)`

For instance, if I want to check something is an array:

```
type( x ) == type( [] )
```

string check:

```
type( x ) == type( '' ) or type( x ) == type( u'' )
```

If you want to check against None, use is

```
x is None
```

Comment: huh? why is it a bad idea in general? It's only a bad idea for strings (for pre 3.0) because there are two types of strings, str and unicode. For arrays, it's a good idea imho.

Comment: @hasen: it is a bad idea overall. What if I define my own type that behaves like an array but, say, fetches values from a database? Your code will fail with my type for no reason.

Comment: @hasen: read the link http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/ of the most voted (+7) answer, by voltronw

Comment: Well, the entire reason (for me atleast) in checking the type is exactly because I want to deal with arrays differently than other types (including types that imitate arrays).

Comment: @hasen: well, that's a really bad idea and your design is broken. Code shouldn't behave in different ways depending on the type of the object passed. That is bug-prone and prevents code reuse, so is generally frowned upon.

Comment: You're wrong. I'll give you a concrete example: django has a template rendering shortcut that can accept either a string or an array of strings. Now, both strings and arrays (lists) are iterable, but in this case, the functions needs to differentiate between them.

Comment: @hasenj, Django is broken and that's a broken design. There should be two different functions here.

Answer (score 3):

i think this should do it

```
if isinstance(obj, str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Type doesn't work on certain classes. If you're not sure of the object's type use the `__class__` method, as so:

```
>>>obj = 'a string'
>>>obj.__class__ == str
True
```

Also see this article
[Type Checking in Python - Siafoo](https://web.archive.org/web/20200704074509/http://www.siafoo.net/article/56)

Answer (score 2):

To get the type, use the `__class__` member, as in `unknown_thing.__class__`

Talk of duck-typing is useless here because it doesn't answer a perfectly good question. In my application code I never need to know the type of something, but it's still useful to have a way to learn an object's type. Sometimes I need to get the actual class to validate a unit test. Duck typing gets in the way there because all possible objects have the same API, but only one is correct. Also, sometimes I'm maintaining somebody else's code, and I have no idea what kind of object I've been passed. This is my biggest problem with dynamically typed languages like Python. Version 1 is very easy and quick to develop. Version 2 is a pain in the buns, especially if you didn't write version 1. So sometimes, when I'm working with a function I didn't write, I need to know the type of a parameter, just so I know what methods I can call on it.

That's where the `__class__` parameter comes in handy. That (as far as I can tell) is the best way (maybe the only way) to get an object's type.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare classes for check level.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf8

class A(object):
    def t(self):
        print 'A'
    def r(self):
        print 'rA',
        self.t()

class B(A):
    def t(self):
        print 'B'

class C(A):
    def t(self):
        print 'C'

class D(B, C):
    def t(self):
        print 'D',
        super(D, self).t()

class E(C, B):
    pass

d = D()
d.t()
d.r()

e = E()
e.t()
e.r()

print isinstance(e, D) # False
print isinstance(e, E) # True
print isinstance(e, C) # True
print isinstance(e, B) # True
print isinstance(e, (A,)) # True
print e.__class__ >= A, #False
print e.__class__ <= C, #False
print e.__class__ <  E, #False
print e.__class__ <= E  #True
```

Answer (score 0):

Because type returns an object, you can access de the name of the object using object.**name**

Example:

```
years = 5
user = {'name':'Smith', 'age':20}

print(type(a).__name__)
```

*output:* 'int'

```
print(type(b).__name__ )
```

*output:* 'dict'