# How to properly check object types in Python?

Tags: python, types, comparison, isinstance

Problem: I have to check that the a returned value is a Python dictionary.

Q1. Which of these options is the proper way to do this?

```
type(x) == dict

type(x) == type(dict)

isinstance(d, dict)
```

Then there are the other variants using `is` operator instead of `==`.

Q2. [Many people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707674/how-to-compare-type-of-an-object-in-python) say that checking the type of an object is generally a bad practice, but regarding to my initial problem, do I have any other choice?

Comment: Do you need it to be a dictionary or do you need to access items on it?

Comment: And anyways, the question you linked already provides the answer.

Comment: @Garet I need to be a dictionary because I'll use it to .update another dict.

Comment: @Garet I'm sorry, I missed [the right answer for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707674/how-to-compare-type-of-an-object-in-python/707878#707878). Though, my Q2 is not covered.

Comment: Fair enough, S.Lott answer is the right one in your case (I might get him an up vote despite our recent history... :D )

Comment: If you ever do actually need to check type, the Python docs tell you to use `isinstance` not `type`, and says to use `isinstance` with abstract base classes (from collections, numbers, io) to see if an object supports a particular interface.

Comment: "I need to be a dictionary because I'll use it to .update another dict." Except that isn't actually the case. Even something as weird as `x = {}; x.update(['hi'])` will work. Try reading `help(dict.update)`, and then see if you can guess what the result will be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Q1. Which of these options is the proper way to do this?

Don't waste time on type checking.

It's error-prone because it's based on assumptions.

> Q2. ... do I have any other choice?

Yes do this.

```
try:
    x.the_dict_operation()
except TypeError:
    # x was not the expected type for the operation
    raise # or whatever.
```

In most cases, this amounts to "do nothing".

Just write the code.  If "somehow" a malicious sociopath uses the wrong type, it will just crash like it's supposed to.

Comment: +1 a big thanks, now I really understand what "Duck typing" is about.

Comment: This way I have to trust that x.the_dict_operation method still does what it was supposed to do (in my case a plain .update of another dictionary). Isn't this a potential problem?

Comment: @Guandalino: since you're using the user-supplied dict to update your own dict, your own dict's `.update()` method is getting called. If you can't trust that...

Comment: Let it just crash and fix the code, instead of lots of checks. I think that is good practice.

Comment: @Guandalino: "This way I have to trust..." What's the alternative?  Magical introspection to assert that "somehow" the code is bug-free, satisfies all the contract specifications in the all of the "require" and "assure" clauses in the original design?  There's no possible way to do anything other than trust.

Answer (score 2):

Rely on *behaviour*, not on actual type (see other answers).

Lot of objects can act like dictionaries, you don't want to force users of your function/API to use plain dicts, right?

On the pragmatic side:

```
>>> type({})
<type 'dict'>
>>> dict
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(dict)
<type 'type'>
>>> isinstance({}, dict)
True
>>> isinstance("", dict)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `__getitem__` rather than verifying the type. If you really want to type-check, any is fine (well, except `type(x) == type(dict)`, that will never be true for a `dict` instance). `isinstance` is probably the most standard way to do it.

Comment: `__getitem__` doesn't have anything to do with dict.  Lots of objects have `__getitem__` that aren't dicts.  For what he's doing (checking if the object can be passed to `{}.update`), this is particularly wrong: there are objects which can be passed to that function which don't have `__getitem__`.  He wants to check if the object is iterable.

Comment: @Glenn It needs to be iterable such that the iterated-over elements are each iterable, such that there are 2 elements in each of those. :)