# Checking type of variable against multiple types doesn't produce expected result

Tags: python, if-statement, types, boolean-logic

Task:

1. Define a function, `distance_from_zero` with one parameter.
2. Have that function do the following:

   - Check the type of the input it receives.
   - If the type is `int` or `float`, the function should return the absolute value of the function input.
   - If the type is any other type, the function should return `"Not an integer or float!"`

My answer that does not work:

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
    if type(d) == int or float:
        return abs(d)
    else:
        return "Not an integer or float!"
```

Comment: what about indents? And ```if type(d) == int or float:``` looks strange you should try ```if type(d) in (int, float):``` or ```if isinstance(d, (int, float)):```

Comment: I corrected the indentation as I think this is just an formatting problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Also: [Python check if isinstance any type in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311258/python-check-if-isinstance-any-type-in-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use this kind of "natural language based logic concatenation". What I mean is that you need to state the parts of your logical conditions explicitly.

```
if type(d) == int or type(d) == float
```

This way you have the two comparisons, which stand for themselves: `if type(d) == int` as well as `type(d) == float`. The results of this can be combined with the `or`-operator.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `isinstance` here rather than `type`:

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
    if isinstance(d, (int, float)):
        return abs(d)
    else:
        return "Not an integer or float!"
```

if `type(d) == int or float` is always going to be `True` as it is evaluated as `float` and it is a `True` value:

```
>>> bool(float)
True
```

help on `isinstance`:

```
>>> print isinstance.__doc__
isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool

Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
With a type as second argument, return whether that is the object's type.
The form using a tuple, isinstance(x, (A, B, ...)), is a shortcut for
isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ... (etc.).
```

Related : [How to compare type of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707674/how-to-compare-type-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

The type check should be

```
if isinstance(d, int) or isinstance(d, float):
```

which can be abbreviated

```
if isinstance(d, (int, float))
```

What your current code is testing is

```
(type(d) == int) or float
```

or, in words: "either the type of `d` is `int`, or `float` is true". For technical reasons, this entire expression is always true. Logical expressions in programming languages have to be specified a bit more precisely than in natural language.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, if statements don't work like they do in plain language. If you want to say something like `This fruit is an apple or an orange`, you need to program it as

```
if type(fruit) == Apple or type(fruit) == Orange
```

More specific to your problem, you want to use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type), as `isinstance()` will properly account for subclassing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/264775) for more details.

So you should end up with something like

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
    if isinstance(d, int) or isinstance(d, float):
        return abs(d)
    else:
        return "Not an integer or float!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct code:

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
        if type(d) in (int, float):
                return abs(d)
        else:
                return "Not an integer or float!"

print distance_from_zero(3)
print distance_from_zero(-5.4)
print distance_from_zero("abc")
```

Output:

```
3
5.4
Not an integer or float!
```

Please be aware of indention, in Python is very important comparing to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is using a little too much of English shortforms.

```
if type(d) == int or float:
```

This means check if the type is `int` or if `float` is `True`, which is not what you want.

```
if type(d) == int or type(d) == float:
```

This will give required result.