# Python math module doesn't have abs

Tags: python

Hi this is a piece of code that is supposed to create a function that returns the absolute value of the inputted integer or float.
Can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it, here's the code and the error. Any help is appreciated!

here is the code for the function:

```
import math
def distance_from_zero(num):
    type_entry = type(num)
    if type_entry == int:
        return math.abs(num)
    elif type_entry == float:
        return math.abs(num)
    else:
        return "Not an integer or float!"
```

here is where I tested out the code by printing the result

```
print distance_from_zero(4)
```

#### here is the error that occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 12, in <module>
  File "python", line 5, in distance_from_zero
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'abs'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python basics (functions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838308/python-basics-functions)

Comment: @JonClements same tutorial question; totally different problem

Comment: What gave you the idea that the `math` module had an `abs()` function? It certainly wasn't from reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=abs#abs).

Comment: ^^^ Hence the S.O. question...

Comment: @martineau probably because starting a tutorial with 'how to read documentation' is a lot less sexy then just writing code that does things, so one tends to guess.

Comment: @Nick: Agreed, but when your code doesn't work and you a hint from the error message, spending a few minutes with Python's online documentation to verify an assumption is often gratifying.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`abs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) is a built-in function, so just replace all occurrences of `math.abs` with `abs`.

You should also use the [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) function for type checking instead of using `type()` and comparing, for example:

```
def distance_from_zero(num):
    if isinstance(num, (int, float)):
        return abs(num)
    else:
        return "Not an integer or float!"
```

Note that you may also want to include `long` and `complex` as valid [numeric types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

Comment: Whoever is calling `distance_from_zero` is expecting a number so I would raise an exception instead of returning a string.

Comment: I agree that raising an exception here makes sense, I was just keeping it consistent with the OP's code.  If you did want to raise an exception it would make the most sense to just use `abs()` then, or if you really want the new name, `distance_from_zero = abs`.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, `abs` is builtin so it isn't imported from the `math` module.

I wanted to comment on your type checking.  Another way that is the most "pythonic" is to use a `try: except:` block to check the type:

```
def distance_from_zero(num):
    try:
        return abs(num)
    except ValueError:
        return "Not an numeric type!"
```

This takes care of the issue that F.J. pointed out, that `long` and `complex` won't be considered.  This example uses "duck typing" (if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck).  If `abs` works, your function succeeds.  If you supply something `abs` doesn't know how to handle a `ValueError` will be raised an it will return your error message.

Answer (score 0):

just try:

```
print(abs(4))
```

Erm i can't make this any shorter.

Here are the availible functions of math: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html
And here are the built-ins that you can call directly without imports: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: I assume he's using the same tutorial as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838308/python-basics-functions) where you are asked to throw an error on certain input.

Comment: @NickT i see, I was on a train and didn't have much time to just give an answer :P

Comment: Actually, you can make this shorter. When `print()`ing a value that's a built-in number such as `int` or `float` the `str()` is redundant and can thus be omitted.

Comment: @blubberdiblub that is true hehe. I wonder if that was the case with Python 2 as well tho?

Comment: @Torxed yes, even Python 2 allowed `print`ing all kinds of built-in datatypes without explicitly converting them to strings, including dicts, lists, tuples, floats, ints (and longs, which were unified with ints in Python 3). The substantial difference between Python 2's and Python 3's `print` is in the former it's a statement while in the latter it's a function. I.e. if you want to print multiple things separated by space, whereas in Python 3 you would write that as `print(foo, bar)`, in Python 2 you'd need to write it as just `print foo, bar`. The parens don't matter for only 1 item, though.

Answer (score 0):

The python math module doesn't have an abs function as this functionality is provided by basic Python. However, looking at the documentation page for python math [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) you can see that they do in fact have a fabs function. That said, you can change the code to either of the following depending on how much you want to be using the math module versus basic python:

```
print str(abs(4))
```

or

```
import math
print str(math.fabs(4))
```

Comment: Throws exception instead of warning if not a number.

Answer (score 0):

And now for something completely different, here is a single expression:

```
(-num, num)[num > 0] if None < num < '' else "Not a number!"
```