# Python check if variable isinstance of any type in list

Tags: python, types, isinstance

How do I compactly perform the following:

```py
var = 7.0
var_is_good = (
    isinstance(var, classinfo1) or
    isinstance(var, classinfo2) or
    isinstance(var, classinfo3)
)
```

Answer (score 380, accepted):

`isinstance()` takes a *tuple* of classes for the second argument. It'll return true if the first argument is an instance of *any* of the types in that sequence:

```
isinstance(var, (classinfo1, classinfo2, classinfo3))
```

In other words, `isinstance()` **already** offers this functionality, out of the box.

From the [`isinstance()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

> If *classinfo* is neither a class object nor a type object, **it may be a tuple of class or type objects, or may recursively contain other such tuples (other sequence types are not accepted).**

Emphasis mine; note the recursive nature; `(classinfo1, (classinfo2, classinfo3))` is also a valid option.

Answer (score 38):

From Python 3.10 you can use the new [New Type Union Operator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator), e.g. :

```
isinstance(var, classinfo1 | classinfo2)
```

See [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) for details.

Answer (score 18):

You were pretty close with the title of your question already. You could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a list:

```
var = 7.0
var_is_good = any([isinstance(var, classinfo1),
                   isinstance(var, classinfo2),
                   isinstance(var, classinfo3), ...
                   isinstance(var, classinfoN)])
```

But looking in the docs of [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) reveals:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns false. If classinfo is not a class (type object), **it may be a tuple of type objects**, or may recursively contain other such tuples (other sequence types are not accepted). If classinfo is not a type or tuple of types and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.

This means the better way to do it is

```
var = 7.0
var_is_good = isinstance(var, (classinfo1,
                               classinfo2,
                               classinfo3,
                               ...,
                               classinfoN))
```

Comment: Repeating `isinstance` with only the `classinfo` changing doesn't seem very Pythonic to me.

Comment: Try  `var.__class__`. Is that what you want? @Makoto: I agree. Not Pythonic  at all!

Comment: @Makoto Yup. But that was something D Adams could probably have easily found by searching the docs for "any". I've expanded my answer to the better version ... but obviously Martijn Pieters was faster ... once again.

Comment: `any()` with a list is.. pointless. Use a generator expression if you must use `any()`, then at least you get the benefit of the early exit.

Comment: I think the `isinstance` with tuple is the way to go. I just wanted to mention the solution with `any` as it seemed to be what he is asking for in the title.

Answer (score 8):

This will solve your problem:

```
valid_instance_types = <tuple of types you want to allow>
var_is_good = isinstance(var, valid_instance_types)
```

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) there are a lot of ways you can pass values of types in to `isinstance`.

You might also look into (unfortunately named) [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous) if you're trying to do a more complicated validation of which this is just a part.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't be using `isinstance`, but what you're wanting to do can be accomplished with the [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) builtin function.

```
var_is_good = any(isinstance(var, t) for t in [type1, type2, type3])
```

Comment: This is overkill; `isinstance()` offers the functionality out of the box without using `any()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't realize that isinstance can take multiple types, but I feel like the answer is still a good one because the question can be taken more broadly to be "How do I check if any of the return values from a particular function with different params is true"

Comment: Whether or not you should use `isinstance()` is irrelevant.

Comment: @ChadS. I would like to ask you why do you think he shouldn't use `isinstance()`? Thank you.

Comment: Because python eschews type checking. It's a lot of extra code (and CPU cycles) for little benefit. Duck typing is preferred.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I had to jump in. In python3, where every class is a type, `isinstance()` offers a lot of power. Without isinstance, if you're trying to parse a parameter that accepts a list or a dict, `isinstance` would appear to be the quickest way to get an answer short of checking attributes or catching exceptions.