# how to check the dtype of a column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use different functions to treat numeric columns and string columns. What I am doing now is really dumb:

```
allc = list((agg.loc[:, (agg.dtypes==np.float64)|(agg.dtypes==np.int)]).columns)
for y in allc:
    treat_numeric(agg[y])    

allc = list((agg.loc[:, (agg.dtypes!=np.float64)&(agg.dtypes!=np.int)]).columns)
for y in allc:
    treat_str(agg[y])
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? E.g.

```
for y in agg.columns:
    if(dtype(agg[y]) == 'string'):
          treat_str(agg[y])
    elif(dtype(agg[y]) != 'string'):
          treat_numeric(agg[y])
```

Comment: `string` is not a dtype

Comment: related question to get best python type 'underneath' the dtype, e.g. Object which can be string, or int, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73560255/how-to-get-the-real-data-type-of-each-column/77390861#77390861

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can access the data-type of a column with [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dtype.html):

```
for y in agg.columns:
    if(agg[y].dtype == np.float64 or agg[y].dtype == np.int64):
          treat_numeric(agg[y])
    else:
          treat_str(agg[y])
```

Comment: Hi David, 

Can you comment as to why you included == np.float64 ? Arn't we trying to convert to floats? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanChase The OP in this question never said he was converting to floats, he just needed to know whether to use an (unspecified) `treat_numeric` function. Since he included `agg.dtypes==np.float64` as an option, I did as well.

Comment: There are more numeric types in numpy than these two, everything under `number` here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html The general solution is `is_numeric_dtype(agg[y])`

Answer (score 164):

In `pandas 0.20.2` you can do:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

is_string_dtype(df['A'])
>>>> True

is_numeric_dtype(df['B'])
>>>> True
```

So your code becomes:

```
for y in agg.columns:
    if (is_string_dtype(agg[y])):
        treat_str(agg[y])
    elif (is_numeric_dtype(agg[y])):
        treat_numeric(agg[y])
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for older pandas versions? I get the error: No module named api.types.

Comment: `pandas.core.common.is_numeric_dtype` has existed since Pandas 0.13, and it does the same thing, but it was deprecated in favour of `pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype` in 0.19, I think

Comment: It is most native answer. But one should be aware of some [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381708/caveats-while-checking-dtype-in-pandas-dataframe) here.

Comment: Or `df.apply(pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype)` for processing entire dataframe

Comment: Bless you kind sir.

Answer (score 57):

I know this is a bit of an old thread but with pandas 19.02, you can do:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).apply(your_function)
df.select_dtypes(exclude=['string','object']).apply(your_other_function)
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Comment: good answer altho I'd probably do `include[np.number]` (to also include ints and 32 bit floats) for first line and `exclude[object]` for the second line.  Strings are objects as far as dtypes are concerned.  In fact, including 'string' with object gives me an error.

Comment: seems that "string" is not supported anymore, "object" must be used instead. But definitively the right answer :)

Comment: Also should be noticed that `'period'` dtype is raising `NotImplementedError` for now (pandas 0.24.2). So one may have need some handmade post processing.

Answer (score 48):

Asked question title is general, but authors use case stated in the body of the question is specific. So any other answers may be used.

But in order to fully answer the ***title question*** it should be clarified that it seems like all of the approaches may *fail* in some cases and require some rework. I reviewed all of them (and some additional) in decreasing of reliability order (in my opinion):

### 1. Comparing types directly via `==` (accepted answer).

Despite the fact that this is accepted answer and has most upvotes count, I think this method should not be used at all. Because in fact this approach is **discouraged** in python as mentioned several times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707674/how-to-compare-type-of-an-object-in-python).
But if one still want to use it - should be aware of some pandas-specific dtypes like `pd.CategoricalDType`, `pd.PeriodDtype`, or `pd.IntervalDtype`. Here one have to use extra `type( )` in order to recognize dtype correctly:

```py
s = pd.Series([pd.Period('2002-03','D'), pd.Period('2012-02-01', 'D')])
s
s.dtype == pd.PeriodDtype   # Not working
type(s.dtype) == pd.PeriodDtype # working 

>>> 0    2002-03-01
>>> 1    2012-02-01
>>> dtype: period[D]
>>> False
>>> True
```

Another caveat here is that type should be pointed out precisely:

```py
s = pd.Series([1,2])
s
s.dtype == np.int64 # Working
s.dtype == np.int32 # Not working

>>> 0    1
>>> 1    2
>>> dtype: int64
>>> True
>>> False
```

### 2. `isinstance()` approach.

This method has not been mentioned in answers so far.

So if direct comparing of types is not a good idea - lets try built-in python function for this purpose, namely - `isinstance()`.
It fails just in the beginning, because assumes that we have some objects, but `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame` may be used as just empty containers with predefined `dtype` but no objects in it:

```py
s = pd.Series([], dtype=bool)
s

>>> Series([], dtype: bool)
```

But if one somehow overcome this issue, and wants to access each object, for example, in the first row and checks its dtype like something like that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'int': [12, 2], 'dt': [pd.Timestamp('2013-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20')]},
                  index = ['A', 'B'])
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].dtype, 'is_int64 = %s' % isinstance(df.loc['A', col], np.int64)

>>> (dtype('int64'), 'is_int64 = True')
>>> (dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'is_int64 = False')
```

It will be misleading in the case of mixed type of data in single column:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [12, pd.Timestamp('2013-01-02')]},
                  index = ['A', 'B'])
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[col].dtype, 'is_int64 = %s' % isinstance(df2.loc['A', col], np.int64)

>>> (dtype('O'), 'is_int64 = False')
```

And last but not least - this method cannot directly recognize `Category` dtype. As stated in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#data-munging):

> Returning a single item from categorical data will also return the value, not a categorical of length “1”.

```py
df['int'] = df['int'].astype('category')
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].dtype, 'is_int64 = %s' % isinstance(df.loc['A', col], np.int64)

>>> (CategoricalDtype(categories=[2, 12], ordered=False), 'is_int64 = True')
>>> (dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'is_int64 = False')
```

So this method is also almost inapplicable.

### 3. `df.dtype.kind` approach.

This method yet may work with empty `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrames` but has another problems.

First - it is unable to differ some dtypes:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'prd'  :[pd.Period('2002-03','D'), pd.Period('2012-02-01', 'D')],
                   'str'  :['s1', 's2'],
                   'cat'  :[1, -1]})
df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype('category')
for col in df:
    # kind will define all columns as 'Object'
    print (df[col].dtype, df[col].dtype.kind)

>>> period[D] O
>>> object O
>>> category O
```

Second, what is actually still unclear for me, it even returns on some dtypes [None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384938/pandas-series-dtype-kind-is-none-for-pd-interval).

### 4. `df.select_dtypes` approach.

This is almost what we want. This method designed inside pandas so it handles most corner cases mentioned earlier - empty DataFrames, differs numpy or pandas-specific dtypes well. It works well with single dtype like `.select_dtypes('bool')`. It may be used even for selecting groups of columns based on dtype:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({'bool' :[False, True], 'int64':[-1,2], 'int32':[-1,2],'float': [-2.5, 3.4],
                     'compl':np.array([1-1j, 5]),
                     'dt'   :[pd.Timestamp('2013-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20')],
                     'td'   :[pd.Timestamp('2012-03-02')- pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20'),
                              pd.Timestamp('2010-07-12')- pd.Timestamp('2000-11-10')],
                     'prd'  :[pd.Period('2002-03','D'), pd.Period('2012-02-01', 'D')],
                     'intrv':pd.arrays.IntervalArray([pd.Interval(0, 0.1), pd.Interval(1, 5)]),
                     'str'  :['s1', 's2'],
                     'cat'  :[1, -1],
                     'obj'  :[[1,2,3], [5435,35,-52,14]]
                    })
test['int32'] = test['int32'].astype(np.int32)
test['cat'] = test['cat'].astype('category')
```

Like so, as stated in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```py
test.select_dtypes('number')

>>>     int64   int32   float   compl   td
>>> 0      -1      -1   -2.5    (1-1j)  -1693 days
>>> 1       2       2    3.4    (5+0j)   3531 days
```

On may think that here we see first unexpected (at used to be for me: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387358/pd-dataframe-select-dtypes-inculdes-timedelta-dtype)) results - `TimeDelta` is included into output `DataFrame`. But as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56387413/10711194) in contrary it should be so, but one have to be aware of it. Note that `bool` dtype is skipped, that may be also undesired for someone, but it's due to `bool` and `number` are in different "[subtrees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html#)" of numpy dtypes. In case with bool, we may use `test.select_dtypes(['bool'])` here.

Next restriction of this method is that for current version of pandas (0.24.2), this code: `test.select_dtypes('period')` will raise `NotImplementedError`.

And another thing is that it's unable to differ strings from other objects:

```py
test.select_dtypes('object')

>>>     str     obj
>>> 0    s1     [1, 2, 3]
>>> 1    s2     [5435, 35, -52, 14]
```

But this is, first - already [mentioned](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) in the docs. And second - is not the problem of this method, rather the way strings are stored in `DataFrame`. But anyway this case have to have some post processing.

### 5. `df.api.types.is_XXX_dtype` approach.

This one is intended to be most robust and native way to achieve dtype recognition (path of the module where functions resides says by itself) as i suppose. And it works almost perfectly, but still have [at least one caveat and still have to somehow distinguish string columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381708/caveats-while-checking-dtype-in-pandas-dataframe).

Besides, this may be subjective, but this approach also has more 'human-understandable' `number` dtypes group processing comparing with `.select_dtypes('number')`:

```py
for col in test.columns:
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(test[col]):
        print (test[col].dtype)

>>> bool
>>> int64
>>> int32
>>> float64
>>> complex128
```

No `timedelta` and `bool` is included. Perfect.

My pipeline exploits exactly this functionality at this moment of time, plus a bit of post hand processing.

### Output.

Hope I was able to argument the main point - that all discussed approaches may be used, but only **`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes()`** and **`pd.api.types.is_XXX_dtype`** should be really considered as the applicable ones.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to mark the type of a dataframe column as a string, you can do:

```py
df['A'].dtype.kind
```

An example:

```py
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a',1.2],[2,'b',2.3]])
In [9]: df[0].dtype.kind, df[1].dtype.kind, df[2].dtype.kind
Out[9]: ('i', 'O', 'f')
```

The answer for your code:

```py
for y in agg.columns:
    if(agg[y].dtype.kind == 'f' or agg[y].dtype.kind == 'i'):
          treat_numeric(agg[y])
    else:
          treat_str(agg[y])
```

Note:

- `uint` and `UInt` are of kind `u`, not kind `i`.
- Consider the [dtype introspection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_utility_functions.html#dtype-introspection) utility functions, e.g. [`pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_integer_dtype.html).

Comment: The  issue with `...dtype.kind` is that it provides `'O'` for both period and string/object. One is better off using `pd.api.types.is_...` variants.

Answer (score 7):

### To pretty print the column data types

To check the data types after, for example, an import from a file

```py
def printColumnInfo(df):
    template="%-8s %-30s %s"
    print(template % ("Type", "Column Name", "Example Value"))
    print("-"*53)
    for c in df.columns:
        print(template % (df[c].dtype, c, df[c].iloc[1]) )
```

Illustrative output:

```
Type     Column Name                    Example Value
-----------------------------------------------------
int64    Age                            49
object   Attrition                      No
object   BusinessTravel                 Travel_Frequently
float64  DailyRate                      279.0
```