# How can I check the dtype of the contents of a column in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

This question is related to [how to check the dtype of a column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697773/how-to-check-the-dtype-of-a-column-in-python-pandas).

An empty pandas dataframe is created. Following this, it's filled with data. How can I then check if any of its columns contain `complex` types?

```
index = [np.array(['foo', 'qux'])]
columns = ["A",  "B"]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df.loc['foo']["A"] = 1 + 1j
df.loc['foo']["B"] = 1
df.loc['qux']["A"] = 2
df.loc['qux']["B"] = 2

print df
for type in df.dtypes:
    if type == complex:
        print type
```

At the moment, I get the type as `object` which isn't useful.

```
          A  B
foo  (1+1j)  1
qux       2  2
```

Comment: You'd have to do `type(df['A'].iloc[0])` assuming all values are the same, the `np.object` dtype is used for python object representation

Comment: You could do `isinstance(df.A.iloc[0], complex)`?

Comment: @EdChum in my case some of the values are real, and some complex!

Comment: having mixed dtypes will be problematic, additionally if the types are not numpy friendly types you will find you will lose the performance gain of using pandas meaning that you will lose vectorised operations, all you will gain is easier indexing semantics

Comment: `(1+1j)` is a plain Python `complex` object. `np.complex128(1+1j)` is a NumPy `complex128` object. You need to use values with native NumPy dtypes to get `df.dtypes` to report non-object dtypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series([1, 3.4, 2 + 1j], dtype=np.object)
s

0         1
1       3.4
2    (2+1j)
dtype: object
```

If I use `pd.to_numeric`, it will upcast the `dtype` to `complex` if any are complex

```
pd.to_numeric(s).dtype

dtype('complex128')
```

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this, you can apply this to the whole dataframe with `df.apply(pd.to_numeric)`