# Caveats while checking dtype in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Guided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697773/how-to-check-the-dtype-of-a-column-in-python-pandas/45568211#45568211) answer I started to build up pipe for processing columns of dataframe based on its dtype. But after getting some unexpected output and some debugging i ended up with test dataframe and test dtype checking:

```py
# Creating test dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame({'bool' :[False, True], 'int':[-1,2],'float': [-2.5, 3.4],
                     'compl':np.array([1-1j, 5]),
                     'dt'   :[pd.Timestamp('2013-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20')],
                     'td'   :[pd.Timestamp('2012-03-02')- pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20'),
                              pd.Timestamp('2010-07-12')- pd.Timestamp('2000-11-10')],
                     'prd'  :[pd.Period('2002-03','D'), pd.Period('2012-02-01', 'D')],
                     'intrv':pd.arrays.IntervalArray([pd.Interval(0, 0.1), pd.Interval(1, 5)]),
                     'str'  :['s1', 's2'],
                     'cat'  :[1, -1],
                     'obj'  :[[1,2,3], [5435,35,-52,14]]
                    })
test['cat'] = test['cat'].astype('category')
test
test.dtypes

# Testing types
types = list(test.columns)
df_types = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(types),len(types)), dtype=bool),
                        index = ['is_'+el for el in types],
                        columns = types)
for col in test.columns:
    df_types.at['is_bool', col] = pd.api.types.is_bool_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_int' , col] = pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_float',col] = pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_compl',col] = pd.api.types.is_complex_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_dt'  , col] = pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_td'  , col] = pd.api.types.is_timedelta64_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_prd' , col] = pd.api.types.is_period_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_intrv',col] = pd.api.types.is_interval_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_str' , col] = pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_cat' , col] = pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(test[col])
    df_types.at['is_obj' , col] = pd.api.types.is_object_dtype(test[col])

# Styling func
def coloring(df):
    clr_g = 'color : green'
    clr_r = 'color : red'
    mask = ~np.logical_xor(df.values, np.eye(df.shape[0], dtype=bool))
    # OUTPUT
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, clr_g, clr_r),
                        index = df.index,
                        columns = df.columns)

# OUTPUT colored
df_types.style.apply(coloring, axis=None)
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

```py
bool                  bool
int                  int64
float              float64
compl           complex128
dt          datetime64[ns]
td         timedelta64[ns]
prd              period[D]
intrv    interval[float64]
str                 object
cat               category
obj                 object
```

[image]

Almost everything is good, but this test code produces two questions:

1. The most strange here is that `pd.api.types.is_string_dtype` fires
   on `category` dtype. Why is that? Should it be treated as 'expected'
   behavior?
2. Why `is_string_dtype` and  `is_object_dtype` fires on each
   other? This is a bit expected, because even in `.dtypes` both types
   are noted as `object`, but it would be better if someone clarify it
   step by step.

P.s.: Bonus question - am i right when thinking that pandas has its internal tests that should be passed when building new release (like df_types from test code, but not with 'coloring in red' rather 'recording info about errors')?

EDIT: pandas version `0.24.2`.

Comment: Very, very well-asked question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to `is_string_dtype` being a fairly loose check, with [the implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7f318658b92155678b31780722277d1f8c8df569/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py#L651-L654) even having a TODO note to make it more strict, linking to [Issue #15585](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15585).

The reason this check is not strict is because there isn't a dedicated string dtype in `pandas`, and instead strings are just stored with `object` dtype, which could really store anything.  As such, a more strict check would likely introduce a performance overhead.

To answer your questions:

1. This is a result of `CategoricalDtype.kind` being set to `'O'`, which is one of the loose checks `is_string_dtype` does.  This could probably change in the future given the TODO note, so it's not something I'd rely upon.
2. Since strings are stored as `object` dtype it makes sense for `is_object_dtype` to fire on strings, and I'd consider this behavior to be reliable as the implementation will almost certainly not change in the immediate future. The reverse is true due to the reliance on `dtype.kind` in `is_string_dtype`, which has the same caveats as with categoricals described above.
3. Yes, `pandas` has a test suite that will run automatically on various CI services for every PR that's created. The test suite includes checks similar to what you're doing.

One tangentially related note to add: there is a library called [`fletcher`](https://github.com/xhochy/fletcher) that uses Apache Arrow to implement a more native string type in a way that's compatible with `pandas`.  It's still under development and probably doesn't currently have support for all the string operations that `pandas` does.

Comment: Wish I could just open github corresponding code file and inspect it as freely as you do, before someone points its exact place :). Will work for that. Thanks for all answers, really helpful to better understand the problem.