# Pandas.Series.dtype.kind is None for pd.interval

Tags: python, pandas, intervals, series

Test code:

```py
s = pd.Series(pd.array([pd.Interval(0,1.2), pd.Interval(5,123)]))
s.dtype
s.dtype.kind is None

>>> interval[float64]
>>> True
```

Is it some bug or made intentionally? If latter - for what reason?

Comment: But there are others 'pandas-only' specific dtypes - period, category as example. But for them `.dtype.kind` returns `O` - object.

Comment: It should be noted that period and category _are_ currently implemented via the extension array interface (same with interval and datetimetz).  It's the custom dtype object that determines `kind`, and the custom dtypes themselves have been around since before the extension array interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is appearing as `None` is simply because the implementation of `IntervalDtype` [explicitly sets `kind = None`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7f318658b92155678b31780722277d1f8c8df569/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py#L910).  This should probably be updated to `'O'`, though some care is needed here as it will result in unintended side effects, e.g. this would cause `is_string_dtype` to return `True` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401142/10711194)).

Comment: I think it also should be mention [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401142/10711194) `is_string_dtype` checking would become problem.