# plt.boxplot(df[col]) fails because 8th column is text, need to exclude

Tags: python, plotly

## Detect outliers with boxplots and histograms

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 30))
i = 0
for col in feature_vars:
i += 1
plt.subplot(9, 4, i)
plt.boxplot(df[col])
plt.title('{}'.format(col), fontsize=9)
plt.hist(df[col])
plt.suptitle('Detect Outliers', fontsize=16, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='center',
fontweight='bold')
plt.savefig('charts/Detect_Outlier_Plots.png', dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='g', orientation='portrait',
format=None, transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.0, metadata=None)
plt.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the for loop, check for the dtype (datatype) of the column. Either check for 'object' and then skip, or check for is_numeric and then don't skip:

[how to check the dtype of a column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697773/how-to-check-the-dtype-of-a-column-in-python-pandas)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html