# How to check if all elements in a list are whole numbers

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

If I have a list such as :

```
List = [12,6,3,5,1.2,5.5]
```

Is there a way I can check if all the numbers are whole numbers? I tried something like

```
def isWhole(d): 
if (d%1 == 0 ) : for z in List return true.
```

That is obviously terribly wrong. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe related: [How to compare type of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/707674/2596334).

Comment: What is a whole number (programatically speaking)?  Are only `integers` whole numbers?  Then what about `bool` (`True` and `False`) which inherits from `int`?  Or is a whole number anything that `1` divides into evenly?  That would make `complex(1,0)` and `fractions.Fraction(1,1)` whole numbers.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Voting to close as "Unclear what you are asking" because the definition of "whole number" is unspecified.

Comment: Also, in mathematics whole numbers are not negative.  So should negatives be excluded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want integers and floats that are equal to integers?

```
def is_whole(d):
    """Whether or not d is a whole number."""
    return isinstance(d, int) or (isinstance(d, float) and d.is_integer())
```

In use:

```
>>> for test in (1, 1.0, 1.1, "1"):
    print(repr(test), is_whole(test))


1 True # integer 
1.0 True # float equal to integer
1.1 False # float not equal to integer
'1' False # neither integer nor float
```

You can then apply this to your list with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
if all(map(is_whole, List)):
```

or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
if all(is_whole(d) for d in List):
```

Comment: Okay thanks for this. I think this is the right direction i need to go. So using the "if all(map(is_whole, List)):" How do it print out  if the individual elements come out as True or False?

Comment: Swap `if any(...):` for `list(...)` or a list comprehension, e.g. `[is_whole(d) for d in [12, 6, 3, 5, 1.2, 5.5]] == [True, True, True, True, False, False]`.

Comment: `is_whole` evaluates `True` and `False` as whole numbers.  Should it?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that's a good question - as `bool` is a subclass of `int`, `isinstance(d, int)` evaluates `True` for `d = True`. If this were *not* the desired behaviour, an initial check `if not isinstance(d, bool)` would need to be added.

Comment: Okay. Got it to work. Thanks very much for this. Is there an output for this where if one evaluates to be True then I can print something specifically?

Comment: ...what? Do you mean if *exactly one* evaluates to `True`? `sum(...)` will give you the number that evaluate to `True`, or have a look at [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Comment: Yeah so say in my example. If one of my elements evaluates to be True then I want it to be able to print out.

Comment: `for item in List:if is_whole(item):print item` or `print([item for item in List if is_whole(item)]) # may print an empty list`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't really clear. Say if one of items in the list = true. I want to print out a separate message. For example something like if item for item in list if is_whole(item): print("Message").

Comment: That hasn't clarified anything (for one thing, whitespace is important in Python - it's unreadable in comments, especially when not even formatted `as code`). Why don't you make an actual effort - try some things in the interpreter (e.g. `sum`, as I've already mentioned)? Without seeing a minimal example of the code along with inputs and expected and actual outputs, how are we supposed to know what's wrong with whatever you have?

Comment: I've been trying for for the past 20 minutes. I'm just very new to Python. Basically, so far if I have a list of elements and they all print out true and false. For example 4.0= True, 2.85= false,  2.22= false. I want to try and see that if at least one of the elements came out as true, which will be the 4.0 in the example then I will print out a separate string saying True.

Comment: Then, as I have *already suggested*, you want `any` instead of `all`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for a list L:

```
def isWhole(L):
    for i in L:
        if i%1 != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `isWhole([complex(1,0), fractions.Fraction(1,1), True, False])` evaluates to `True`.  Should it?

Answer (score 1):

List = [12,6,3,5,1.2,5.5]

for i in List:

```
if i%1 != 0 :
    print(False)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

if your list is lst = [12,6,3,5,1.2,5.5]
you can do this.

```
lst = [12,6,3,5,1.2,5.5]
print(all(isinstance(i,int) for i in lst))
```

it prints "True" if your list contains whole numbers, if not "False"