# python how to judge whether a variable is boolean type

Tags: python

In python, how to judge whether a variable is bool type,python 3.6 using

```
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for k in data[i].keys():
            if type(data[i][k]) is types.BooleanType:
                data[i][k] = str(data[i][k])
            row.append(data[i][k])
            #row.append(str(data[i][k]).encode('utf-8'))
        writer.writerow(row)
        row = []
```

but it errors:

```
  if type(data[i][k]) is types.BooleanType:

  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: >>> a=False
>>> isinstance(a, bool)
True
>>> isinstance(a, str)
False

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the type of a Python object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-a-python-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare type of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707674/how-to-compare-type-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 32):

you can check type properly with `isinstance()`

```
isinstance(data[i][k], bool)
```

will return `true` if `data[i][k]` is a bool

Answer (score 3):

```
 isinstance(data[i][k], bool) #returns True if boolean
```

instead of :

```
if type(data[i][k]) is types.BooleanType:
```